# Producing Voronoi diagram in three dimensional

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, voronoi

A Voronoi diagram is a kind of tesselation that divided the medium into polygons in 2D and polyhedrons in 3D.

Although there are many algorithms to construct a Voronoi diagram, some of them are faster than others. Based on my knowledge, Fortune's algorithm is fastest to construct the Voronoi diagram either in two dimensional or three dimensional.

Fortune's algorithm is based on the sweep-line strategy and balanced binary search tree.

Now, I want to implement Fortune's algorithm into three dimensional. I want to know which basically variation is made to fit the algorithm to three dimensional?

Comment: How do you substantiate that Fortune's algorithm is the fastest ? IMO, the Divide & Conquer method (Lee & Schachter) is equally good. I don't know about a 3D version of Fortune's algorithm.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Mentioned in "Computational Geometry 
Algorithms and Applications". So in 3D you first find the Delaunay triangulation and then find the Voronoi diagram?

Comment: To what part of my comment does this answer ?

Comment: The Delaunay triangulation and Voronoi diagram are duals of each other, so that in principle any algorithm can be instantiated for one or the other.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The book is a reference for "Fortune's algorithm is the fastest". DT and v are dual but what about the time consuming of the algorithm?

Comment: On what page ??

Comment: Fortune's algorithm doesn't have a 3D generalization as far as I know -- you'd need a completely different core data structure to make a sweep-plane work. Why do you want to implement your own 3D Voronoi? It's a ton of work to get the edge cases right, never mind efficiency: http://www.gdmc.nl/publications/2007/Computing_3D_Voronoi_Diagram.pdf

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3787491/14578, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63363508/781723, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/35739/4274.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).